# Does HUB has calculation function?

Tags: cpu

We know the HUB broadcast the frames. I have a question, does it have a CPU for calculate something?

the Switch have MAC address table, then we can know it have calculate function for record MAC address. but how about the HUB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeater hubs don't (didn't) usually have a CPU, although there were a few managed hubs around.

Simple switches don't have a CPU either. All processing is done within an ASIC (or several coupled ASICs), including FCS calculation. Managed switches require a CPU in order to allow a user access to the switch and to configure the ASICs.

Comment: is the hub have `ASIC`?

Comment: Most hubs used (simple) ASICs but you can build a repeater without one.

Comment: @244boy Typically a hub would just replicate traffic and broadcast it to all ports

Comment: @Cown Yeah, I mean does the base function needs a ASIC?

Comment: @244boy A hub does not have an ASIC. It is a dumb device in the network. It knows nothing about those devices that are plugged into that hub. On the other hand, a switch can intelligently manage the data in the network going through it.